# How could i code this more efficiently? - a gulp task

Tags: gulp, gulp-usemin

Maybe someone with a bit more java script experience than myself can answer this. So far I've made a copy & paste from the 'usemin' block as shown in a course. Here's the code:

```
gulp.task('useminTrigger', ['deleteDistFolder'], function() {
  gulp.start("usemin", "usemin-de");
});

gulp.task('usemin', ['styles', 'scripts'], function () {
  return gulp.src("./app/index.html")
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return cssnano()}],
      js: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return uglify()}]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});

gulp.task('usemin-de', ['styles', 'scripts'], function () {
  return gulp.src("./app/de/index.html")
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return cssnano()}],
      js: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return uglify()}]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/de"));
});
```

The script works as it should but maybe there is a easier or more elegant way to code that.

> And with elegant i mean: Is there a way to **merge** the ***usemin***-block together with ***usemin-de***?

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's hard to tell what your question is. Do you want a concise way to run the same task on `./app/index.html` (outputting to `./dist`) and on `./app/de/index.html` (outputting to `./dist/de`)?

Comment: Hello Henry, thanks for the reply. I guess this is a rookie question... :) I guess I actually don't understand all of the code what I've written and need some help to see how it should look like to tell gulp correctly what I want. I've edited my question as you will see to be more clear. Hopefully that helps a bit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) in your `gulp.src` (that is, if you use wildcards to select the files you want processed by your `gulp.task`), the source file structure will be preserved all the way through `gulp.dest`.

To match just `app/index.html` and `app/de/index.html` you could use the glob `'./app/{,de}/index.html'` (it would also work to use `'./app/{,de/}index.html'` or `'./app/{.,de}/index.html'`).

Then your task would be

```js
gulp.task('usemin', ['styles', 'scripts'], function () {
  return gulp.src('./app/{,de}/index.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return cssnano()}],
      js: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return uglify()}]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});
```

That one task will take `./app/index.html` and `./app/de/index.html` as source files and will output the files `./dist/index.html` and `./dist/de/index.html`.

Note that using a glob is necessary - if you just did `gulp.src(['./app/index.html','./app/de/index.html'])` the relative file structure would not be preserved. The processed version of `./app/index.html` would be written to `./dest/index.html`, and then the processed version of `./app/de/index.html` would be written to `./dest/index.html` (overriding the first output file).

Here's a good [glob primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer), and here's a [tester learning tool](http://www.globtester.com/).

Comment: Thanks henry, a very compact solution. I have already read a bit into this topic (your links). I've only used regexp for searching files - a new experience to use it to code for me. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in **Javascript** or **Gulp** keeping you from extracting the function:

**Your Tasks**

```
gulp.task('useminTrigger', ['deleteDistFolder'], function() {
    gulp.start("usemin", "usemin-de");
});

gulp.task('usemin', ['styles', 'scripts'], function () {

    return createMinificationPipe("./app/index.html", "./dist");
});

gulp.task('usemin-de', ['styles', 'scripts'], function () {
    return createMinificationPipe("./app/de/index.html", "./dist/de");
});
```

**Common function**

```
function createMinificationPipe(src, dest){
    return gulp.src(src)
        .pipe(usemin({
          css: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return cssnano()}],
          js: [function () {return rev()}, function () {return uglify()}]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and this great split, that was excatly what i was not able to do. I haven't tried it out just yet, but I will update if I have.